# Не получается решить задачу на тему "игра Баше"

Tags: c++

Добрый день еще раз! Попробовал решить задачу на тему "игра Баше" как сразу столкнулся с проблемой при тестировании.
Вот здесь можно прочитать условие задачи: http://www.e-olimp.com/problems/1005

> ### Children of a match is not a toy!
>
> On the table there are N matches. They play two, take turns. A player
>   may take no more than M matches, but not less than one. Took away the
>   last match wins.
>
> Who will win in the regular game - the first or second player?
>
> **Input**
>
> In the first line is the number of T - the number of test cases. In
>   the following T lines are two numbers, separated by a space: N -
>   number of matches in the pile and M - the maximum allowed for the
>   capture of one move.
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 100, 1 ≤ N, M ≤ 2·10<sup>9</sup>.
>
> **Output**
>
> In a single line display a sequence of ones and twos T, 1 - for the
>   case if the right wins the first game and, respectively, 2 - if the
>   player wins the second.

Вот код задачи:

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T; // кол-во тестов
    cin >> T;
    int n,m; // кол-во спичек в пучке; макс.кол-во спичек, разрешенное за 1 ход
    int sum; // сюда мы складываем все кол-во спичек и далее оперируем этой суммой
    for (int i = 0; i < T; ++i) // цикл для кол-ва заданых тестов
        {
            cin >> n >> m; // вводим
            int sum = n; // буду постоянно отнимать нужное кол-во спичек за ход
            int igrok = 0; // счетчик, который определяет какой игрок походил
            while ( sum > 0 ) // второй цикл - пока сумма всех спичек больше нуля игра будет продолжаться, иначе игра закончится и кто-то выйграет
                {
                    int lol = 0; // ромежуточное значение (для суммы), где хранится кол-во спичек, которые убираеются из кучи
                    if (sum % m+1 == 0) {sum -= m; igrok++; } // если кратно m+1: тогда из суммы вычитаем любое кол-во спичек (в данном случе - максимум)
                    else { lol = sum % m+1; sum -= lol; igrok++; } // иначе: находим промежут.значение и вычитаем его из общ.суммы
                    //igrok++;
                }
            if (igrok % 2 == 0) {cout << 2;} // если igrok кратно двум - выйграл второй игрок
            else {cout << 1;} // иначе: выйграл первый
        }
}
```

А вот тест к задаче:
Входные данные :

```
2
7 3
8 3
```

Выходные данные:

```
12
```

А у меня выходит в ответе :

```
11
```

Прошу помочь с решением!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

такие задачи решаются без цикла. Стратегия обычно простая. Если число нацело делиться на кол-во спичек за ход+1, тогда выиграет второй. Если нет, то первый берет остаток и выиграет. Поэтому, алгоритм решения на самом то деле очень простой - прочитать два числа (пусть это будет a и b) и вывести  `a % (b +1) != 0?1:2;`

Решение в лоб:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n, a, b;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      std::cin >> a >> b;
      int r = a % (b + 1);
      std::cout << (r==0?2:1);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Хотя оно и очень простое, но его нужно знать, что бы решить задачу :)
Только у меня вопрос: что значит строка:  "std::cout << (r==0?2:1)"
я понял, что это краткая запись: if-else, но мне не совсем ясно само условие. Почему r сравнивается с нулем?

Comment: и все-таки на счет моего кода: что же там неверно - почему он выдает неверный ответ!? 
Я вроде все проверил - все правильно...

Comment: ок, перепишу его сложнее

    if (r == 0)
      std::cout << "2";
    else
      std::cout << "1";

Почему сравниваю с нулем? проверка на остаток. Если `a % b == 0`, то это значит, что `a` делится нацело на `b`. Для решения олимпиадных задач это нужно знать.


По поводу Вашего кода. С квадратичной сложностью разбираться сложно. Поэтому, я просто рекомендую его выбросить, учитывая, что для этой задачи известна выигрышная стратегия.

Comment: Подождите, может я чего-то не понял, но мне казалось,что условие "if (r == 0)" и "if (r % 2 == 0)" отличаются друг от друга. Разве нет?
Как я вижу, в первом случае мы просто сравниваем полученное число с нулем, во втором же варианте: сравниваем остаток с нулем.
Поправьте, если я что-то не то сказал

Comment: просто потерялся `%2` при переносе.

Comment: Ааа, тогда все понятно! Спасибо еще раз!